# Place a Canvas from a Static Resource in a other Canvas in XAML ? WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, paint, caml

i have a ResourceDictionary with a Canvas defined with x:Key=nameOfCanvasInResource

How do i put it in a other Canvas in xaml ???

Someting like this :

```
 <Canvas Children="{StaticResource nameOfCanvasInResource}">
 </Canvas>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any control that has `Content` property

```
...
<Window.Resources>
    <Canvas x:Key="ResourceCanvas" x:Shared="False">
        <Rectangle Width="100" Stroke="Red" Height="100"></Rectangle>
    </Canvas>
</Window.Resources>
<Canvas>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource ResourceCanvas}"/>
</Canvas>
...
```

`x:Shared="False"` is required for a new copy of canvas if you use it in several places.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `StaticResource` markup extension as a tag like so:

```
<Canvas>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="nameOfCanvasInResource"/>
</Canvas>
```

This avoids the need wrap it in an extra ContentControl